# linux 'screen' command - lowers process priority if detached?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

If I run a program within a `screen` session, and then detach the screen - does the program have lower scheduling priority?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No,** `screen` does not alter the priority of its children in any way (particularly because it wouldn't be able to raise it back on reattaching), and the Linux kernel itself is not even aware of any "detaching".